# How to connect this flat flex cable (FFC) to this connector?

Tags: connector, ffc

Should I somehow open this clip? Can't understand what is a correct way to put the cable inside.

[image: photo of FFC and connector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully rotate up the black actuator, insert cable, rotate actuator back down.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit.